# DC Bus Conditioners in VFD Drives

Tags: power, power-electronics, surge-protection, transient-suppression, vfd

In VFD Drives, DC Bus conditoners are used to protect the DC link supply from transients. Can you please let me know the different scenarios DC Bus of a VF Drive gets these transients and their relation with different drive parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues involved in the design of the DC link supply of a variable-frequency drive (VFD).

In the most common VFD configurations, there is a DC link capacitor bank that limits the DC ripple voltage and supplies the reactive current required by an induction-motor load. The reactive current requirement generally determines the capacitor selection.

When power is initially applied to the VFD, the inrush current can damage the rectifier and the capacitors if it is not limited. There are a number of pre-charge schemes and other measures that are used to limit the charging current.

During steady-state operation, there is a pulse of current into the capacitors that occurs at the peak of each half-cycle of each phase of the supply voltage waveform. That is not a problem for the VFD components, but it represents harmonic distortion of the power current waveform. That can cause distortion of the power line voltage and have negative effects on power distribution components and other connected utilization equipment. It also results in a reduced total power factor. VFDs often have inductance added to the incoming AC lines or the DC link to reduce input current distortion.

There are two basic scenarios involving line voltage transients. High-voltage, short-duration voltage transients can damage the rectifier and possibly other components. Metal oxide varistors are often used to protect against that scenario. Line inductors are also useful in that regard. Lower-voltage repetitive or ringing voltage transients may have sufficient energy to charge the DC bus capacitors to a sufficiently high voltage to damage the inverter components. Input line inductors can also mitigate that problem. Sometimes, connecting a dynamic braking resistor across the bus can help. Ultimately, it may be necessary to eliminate the source of the problem. The source is often the switching of power factor correction capacitors somewhere in the power distribution system.

Of course motor power regeneration can also raise the bus voltage. Either dynamic braking resistors or deceleration rate limitation can be used in that situation. In some cases, braking energy may need to be returned to the supply using a regenerative input section.

Comment: Not trying to nitpick, but it's difficult for me to see the reactive behavior of a capacitor bank to an inductive motor when there's a PWM inverter in between.  Sure, a cap across the motor directly will do that, and that's more-or-less the configuration when the inverter is on, but when you break and reconfigure that connection at the PWM frequency, it becomes easier for me to think of the DC-bus caps as simply a generic reservoir of charge.  Basically a classic linear power supply with a diode-rectifier and enough capacitance to support the entire circuit between input pulses.

Comment: If you look into the phase relationship between the inverter output voltage and current and the current in the anti-parallel diodes across the switching devices, you should be able to appreciate the role of the bus capacitors.

Comment: @CharlesCowie How about cable length & capacitance ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most likely is hard braking.  All that energy has to go somewhere, and it usually ends up in the DC bus all of a sudden.  I've never seen a DC bus conditioner that claims to do that, but I have seen and used braking resistors, which are connected automatically by the drive across its own DC bus as required to bleed off the extra charge.

Lightning is also a possibility, or maybe a non-VFD motor being back-driven faster than its rated speed so that it raises the line voltage (never actually seen that), but I'd say that the most common is active braking by the VFD itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your DC Bus conditoner's are inductor/capacitor/varistor combinations that form a 'backfeed' filter. The transients can be measured in amps or volts, but amps is a better representation. It is equal to the total DC current being consumed and is always present if the VFD is active.
 As an example, a 10 amp electric drill produces 10 amps of noise transients on the AC line (noise and transient are the same thing, but under different context. Noise is a continuous event, while transients are a single pulse of noise selected or created for detailed examination. Fast repeated transients could be called 'noise').
 So the VFD noise transients are equal in current to the current consumption of the VFD while driving the motor. At 100 amps of current consumption the VFD would have 100 amp noise transients, before any filtering.
 The frequency of the noise is equal to the drive frequency of the VFD x 3, for a 3-phase VFD. Most all VFD's use PWM to improve efficiency, but this noise is filtered internally. The fine details of harmonics vs. frequency, etc, would have to be measured under real-world conditions. *My answer is general observations from building and using them.*